# Why sdwebimage can load image successfully when App Transport Security Setting is enabled?

Tags: ios, sdwebimage

As Apple will force us to enable ATS from 2017, I'm doing some investigation work, but have some doubts about the `SDWebImage` class.

If I use the code below, the image will be loaded successfully

```
[self.myImageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://f.hiphotos.baidu.com/image/h%3D200/sign=1c3f18c4524e9258b93481eeac83d1d1/b7fd5266d0160924be0452bbd00735fae6cd3468.jpg"]];
```

But if I use the method in `NSData`, the image won't be loaded.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://f.hiphotos.baidu.com/image/h%3D200/sign=1c3f18c4524e9258b93481eeac83d1d1/b7fd5266d0160924be0452bbd00735fae6cd3468.jpg"]];

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        self.myImageView.image = image;
    });
});
```

How does `SDWebImage` do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make certain that "`NSAllowsArbitraryLoads`" isn't set in your Info.plist file.

As far as I can tell, SDWebImage is subject to the same ATS restrictions that all other apps are under.

For example, when I plug in your URL into SDWebImage's demo app ([in their MasterViewController.m](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/blob/master/Examples/SDWebImage%20Demo/MasterViewController.m) file) and turn off ATS exceptions, I get the "`SDWebImage iOS Demo[6714:130852] App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource load since it is insecure. Temporary exceptions can be configured via your app's Info.plist file.`" message in the Xcode console.

Comment: You're right, SDWebImage is subject to the same ATS restrictions. And I finally found the reason, when I first test the http image loading, I turned the ATS off, so SDWebImage can load the image successfully, but then I turned the ATS on, SDWebImage can still load the image successfully, but that's because SDWebImage cached the image, not loading from the web, so if I change the parameter to another http image url when ATS is on, it will still fail to load.

Answer (score 0):

Unlikely, but maybe, in case of loading failure, SDWebImage looks at the NSURL scheme, and if it's @"http:", it changes it to @"https:"?

```
NSString *absoluteString = url.absoluteString;
if ([absoluteString hasPrefix:@"http:"]) {
    url = [NSURL URLWithString:[@"https:" stringByAppendingString:[absoluteString substringFromIndex:5]]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

might be getting the image from the cache as thats the first place sdwebimage checks before it sends the request to the url.